How to handle two dependent tasks?
Let's say we have task A and task B.
B needs A's result in the middle of B's execution time, and B will wait for A's result by polling.
If A exits (due to failures), B can exit

before A exits (not caused by A, but some other reasons).
after A exits (caused by A or some other reasons).

For the second case, it's possible that B exits much later than A exits, but ideally we want to kill B as soon as possible if we already know A exits.
I wrote some code like this:
import subprocess
import psutil

B_proc = subprocess.Popen(["do_B"])

try:
    subprocess.run(["do_A"], check=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    # We do not detect if B_proc exits or not.
    parent = psutil.Process(B_proc.pid)
    for child in parent.children(recursive=True):
        child.kill()
    parent.kill()
    raise Exception("A exits")

B_proc.communicate()

if B_proc.poll() != 0:
    raise Exception("B exits")

If A exits, we don't detect B's status but just kill it without communicate()/poll() for B.
Is it a correct and elegant way to handle such case? So far, it works fine.

Have you looked at Asyncio? https://realpython.com/async-io-python/

@Forcetti  I simplified the question, and Asyncio is not what we consider, thanks.
